# AS3 having trouble figuring out entering data into parameters

Tags: actionscript-3

AS3
I some what understand perameters but for some reason I just cant fully understand it
say, dog(bark:string, bone:uint, grass:Array)
dog.bark - string, dog.bone - uint, dog.grass - Array.  Right? but then this i dont understand
 public function MenuButtonMain(labl:String) - in code below. theres no other classes with labl in it
its the last class. I somewhat understand but if you could give me a how,why,every possibility and everything you can do with it, as technical as it can whatever itll be a huge help. THANKYOU

```
12   public function MenuButtonMain(labl:String)  { 
13  _btnLabel  =  new TextFieldQ; 
14  JrtnLabel.autoSize  =  TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER; 
15  JrtnLabel.textColor =  OxFFFFFF; 
16  JrtnLabel.text  =  labl; 
17  _btnLabel.mouseEnabled  =  false; 
18  addChild(_btnLabel); 
19 
20  buttonMode = true; 
21  useHandCursor = true; 
22  addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,  onClick, 
23  false, 0, true);
```

Comment: What are you asking exactly? It is not very clear.

Comment: No, dog(bark:string, bone:uint, grass:Array) DOES NOT mean dog.bark - string, dog.bone - uint, dog.grass - Array.  Parameter variables can't not be directly accessed from outside a function.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in the behaviour of the parameter between both example "codes" you provided.

Each of your functions has a name. You use that to call or execute the function.
Each function has a list of parameters that you have to pass to the function when executing it.
Each parameter has a name to identify it and a type that defines what kind of parameter it is.

Hint: As3 is case sensitive. Compare:

```
bark:string
```

with:

```
labl:String
```

The parameters have different names **and** different types.

If you want to know what the code in the body of the function does, you should ask for that.
Your question is way too broad, "how,why,every possibility and everything".

Comment: sorry,public function MenuButtonMain(labl:String) since menuButtonMain is its on class, and theres labl:String in the perameter, what does the labl:String do to MenuButtonMain?  I see this alot and never fully understood it

Comment: It is a parameter, just like the ones you described in your first post.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter is a variable scoped to function.

```
var someAnswer = getAnswer(7);
trace(someAnswer);  // 12

var someAnswer = getAnswer(4);
trace(someAnswer);  // 9

public function getAnswer(someNumber:int):int {
    var tempAnswer:int = 5 + someNumber;
    return tempAnswer;
}
```